# How to make user input show in the middle of input area as user types

Tags: html, forms, input, user-input

I'm new to Web Development and I'm trying to get the user input to stay in the middle of the input box as they type, instead of being on the left. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make input field text in center then you need to assign css property of `text-align: center`

```css
.make-center{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
User Input : <input type="text" class="make-center" value="AnyThing">
```